# Is the hadith of non-renewal of ablution after cupping authentic?

Tags: hadith, authenticity

Daraqutni recorded a hadith about prophet not renewing ablution after cupping and blood flowed from that cut.  **Is this narration authentic or fair (Hasan)**?

> Anas (Radiya Allahu Anhu) narrated that "The Prophet (Sallallahu Alaihi wa Sallam) availed of cupping and prayed without making ablution.  He just washed the place of the cupping (from where the blood was flowing out)." [Reported by Daraqutni]
> <sub>[IslamWeb](https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/87720/)</sub>

Comment: If this view is the view of Ayisha, Umar then surely it must be Sahih as Ayisha was the wife of the Prophet?

Comment: Bayhaqi also narrated through anas